# Installing Grails CXF Plugin

Tags: grails, cxf

I am running Grails v2.4.0 and I have been trying to install the Grails CXF plugin for web services. I downloaded the .zip file for the plugin and then ran the grails install-plugin /path/to/zip. While trying to install, it gives me an error that it can't find this dependency : **org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:2.3.0**. The page where I downloaded this plugin mentions that everything required is in the zip. I can't use maven to download the required files automatically because my work location doesn't allow anything to be downloaded. Is there a list of files required to install CXF manually that I can reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't download the transitive dependencies using Maven, you should be able to exclude them like this:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

plugins {

    compile ":cxf:0.9.0" {
       excludes([ group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws']
       // you may need to exclude quite a few...
    }
}
```

Then download the dependency manually and put them in your lib directory.  For instance, download the cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws from here:  http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.apache.cxf%22%20AND%20a%3A%22cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws%22%20AND%20v%3A%222.3.0%22

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `install-plugin` you should add a dependency to the relevant section of your BuildConfig.groovy, and make sure the `mavenCentral()` repository is enabled.  Uninstall the zip plugin you have already installed and then edit your BuildConfig:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // other repositories as before
        mavenCentral()
    }

    plugins {
        // other plugins as before
        compile ":cxf:0.9.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking mavenCentral is the problem:  "I can't use maven to download the required files automatically because my work location doesn't allow anything to be downloaded."

Comment: When you say "doesn't allow anything to be downloaded", how did you download the plugin zip in the first place? If the issue is that your work requires all all HTTP traffic to go through a proxy then you can configure Grails to use that proxy by using the `add-proxy` and `set-proxy` commands (http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/set-proxy.html).